# Skipping indices in a product

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, operators

I have a matrix $A$ for which I want to compute the quantity $T\lambda_j = \Pi_{\lambda_i\ne \lambda_j} \frac{A - \lambda_i I}{\lambda_j-\lambda_i}$, where $\lambda_i$ ($\lambda_j$) denote the eigenvalues of $A$. How can this be implemented in Mathematica? Just gave a try here:

```
A = {{1, 0, 0, 1},{0, 1, 2, 0},{1, 1, 0, 2},{0, 0, 0, 1}};
Eigenvalues[A]
```

> {2, -1, 1, 1}

```
Tj = Product[(A - Eigenvalues[A][[i]] IdentityMatrix[4])/(
  Eigenvalues[A][[j]] - Eigenvalues[A][[i]]), {i, 1, 4}]
```

Comment: in which part exactly you want to exclude it in Tj !??

Comment: do you want it to be skipped put not Zero right !?

Comment: @Alrubaie, there was a typo in my post. Just edited it. I want the denominator to be non-zero and hence avoid the case for which $i=j$.

Comment: @Alrubaie, my $i$ and $j$ are not the indices in my question. They are the eigenvalues. I should have used something like $\lambda_i$ and $\lambda_j$.

Comment: but why in the product you put EigenValue i don't see this in the math equation!?
im i right to exclude the EigenValue !?

Comment: Let me put it more clearly in next edit.

Comment: ok got you that i j eigenvalues

Comment: i prefer if you name eigenvalues rather than i and j to make it clear

Comment: Is it better now? I put those i and j there just to make contact with the Mathematica code.

Comment: That product is presumably a matrix multiplication?

Comment: Oh yeah. It should be that way.

Answer (score 4):

Here is my pedestrian implementation of your formula:

```
a = {{1, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 2, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 2}, {0, 0, 0, 1}};

ClearAll[t]
t[amat_, j_] := Module[
  {evals, usable},
  evals = Eigenvalues[amat];
  usable = DeleteDuplicates@Cases[evals, Except@evals[[j]] ];
  Dot @@ 
   Table[
     (amat - i IdentityMatrix[Length[amat]])/(evals[[j]] - i),
     {i, usable}
   ]
]

t[a, 4]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You do not provide an example of desired output, so I will let you check whether this is what you expect.

Comment: Thanks, @MarcoB. It leads precisely to the expected result. However, it looks too complicated. Nevertheless, it is fine as it works.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```
Clear[A, evals, T]
A = {{1, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 2, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 2}, {0, 0, 0, 1}};
T[A_?MatrixQ, j_Integer] := With[
  {evals = Eigenvalues[A], id = IdentityMatrix@Length@A},
  Dot @@ Table[
    If[evals[[j]] - evals[[i]] == 0, id, (A - evals[[i]] id)/(evals[[j]] - evals[[i]])],
    {i, Length@A}
    ]
  ]

MatrixForm /@ Array[T[A, #] &, 4]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This

```
A = {{1, 0, 0, 1},{0, 1, 2, 0},{1, 1, 0, 2},{0, 0, 0, 1}};
e=Eigenvalues[A];
Map[(A-e[[#[[1]]]]*IdentityMatrix[4])/(e[[#[[2]]]]-e[[#[[1]]]])&,
  DeleteCases[Tuples[Range[4],2],{i_,i_}]]
```

generates your twelve matricies with i not equal to j.

Put `Dot@@` in front of that `Map` to form the dot product of the 12 matricies.

That works by forming every possible distinct i,j pair and then using those in the `Map`

If it might be easier to read you can also write it this way

```
Map[(ei=e[[#[[1]]]];ej=e[[#[[2]]]];
  (A-ei*IdentityMatrix[4])/(ej-ei))&,
  DeleteCases[Tuples[Range[4],2],{i_,i_}]]
```

Comment: Should `e[[#[[2]]]]-e[[[[1]]]]` be `e[[#[[2]]]]-e[[#[[1]]]]`?

Comment: @ThatGravityGuy Yes! Good catch. Thank you! Corrected.